# Mouse Smooth Scroll Not Working

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, mouse

I found a good scrolling effect http://jsfiddle.net/7ZVb7/1383/ here 
I tried to copy the copy the code but it is not working.
I am new to jQuery therefore I dont know where to place the respective files
Please help in correcting the code

```
<html>

<head>
<script>
$('#parent').bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
    if (!(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta == 120)) {
        var top = parseInt($("#child").css("top"));
        $("#child").css("top", (top - 100) + "px");
        top = parseInt($("#child").css("top"));
        if (top <= -500) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#child").css("top", "-500px");
            }, 100);
        }
    } else {
        var top = parseInt($("#child").css("top"));

        $("#child").css("top", (top + 100) + "px");
        top = parseInt($("#child").css("top"));
        if (top >= 0) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#child").css("top", "0");
            }, 100);
        }
    }
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    #parent {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    margin: auto auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#child {
    width: 200px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: #999;
    margin: auto auto;
    text-align: justify;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
</style>

<head>

<body>
    <script src="src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js""></script>
    <script>
$('#parent').bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
    if (!(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta == 120)) {
        var top = parseInt($("#child").css("top"));
        $("#child").css("top", (top - 100) + "px");
        top = parseInt($("#child").css("top"));
        if (top <= -500) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#child").css("top", "-500px");
            }, 100);
        }
    } else {
        var top = parseInt($("#child").css("top"));

        $("#child").css("top", (top + 100) + "px");
        top = parseInt($("#child").css("top"));
        if (top >= 0) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#child").css("top", "0");
            }, 100);
        }
    }
});
</script>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">aaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa abbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbcc ccccccc ccccccccccc cccccccd ddddddd ddd ddddd ddddd dddddddd aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa abbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbcc ccccccc ccccccccccc cccccccd ddddddd ddd ddddd ddddd dddddddd aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa abbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbcc ccccccc ccccccccccc cccccccd ddddddd ddd ddddd ddddd dddddddd aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa abbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbcc ccccccc ccccccccccc cccccccd ddddddd ddd ddddd ddddd dddddddd aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa abbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbcc ccccccc ccccccccccc cccccccd ddddddd ddd ddddd ddddd dddddddd aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa abbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbcc ccccccc ccccccccccc cccccccd ddddddd ddd ddddd ddddd dddddddd aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaa</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also is my jQuery Code and POSITION of code correct ? I mean have I put the code in the correct place ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [**Animate**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function

```
  $('#parent').bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
    if (!(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta == 120)) {
        var top = parseInt($("#child").css("top"));
        $("#child").css("top", (top - 100) + "px");
        top = parseInt($("#child").css("top"));
        if (top <= -500) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#child").animate({top: "-500px"},1000);
            }, 100);
        }
    } else {
        var top = parseInt($("#child").css("top"));

        $("#child").css("top", (top + 100) + "px");
        top = parseInt($("#child").css("top"));
        if (top >= 0) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                 $("#child").animate({top: "0px"},1000);
            }, 100);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Does not Work even now